# Superset - Unable to add an onclick handler to an anchor(<a>) tag using superset CUSTOM SQL

Tags: parent-child, apache-superset

I am trying to add an onclick handler to the  tag using superset CUSTOM SQL

CONCAT('<a onclick=window.parent?.postMessage({ tab:',"'dashboard'", ',id:',"'123456'",'}',",' *')", 'href=#>' , CLICK_LINK_TEXT, '')

After rendering this element the onclcik attribute is missing in the rendered superset content. it looks like
 Click

is there any way I can add a click handler to an element in superset dashboard. to pass the information to parent window.

Answer (score 0):

you are blocked by the XSS filter.
try to enable it in the feature flags in config.py

FEATURE_FLAGS = {
'ENABLE_JAVASCRIPT_CONTROLS': True
}